# How to insert a new row in react-tabulator

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

So this code is from the official documentation to insert a new row:

```js
$("#add-row").click(function(){
    $("#example-table").tabulator("addRow", {});
});
```

..but i'm using react-tabulator https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabulator

This is the layout below the return method:

```js
<div>
        <button id="add-row" onClick={ReactTabulator("addRow")}>Add Row</button>
      </div>
        <ReactTabulator
          columns={editableColumns}
          data={data}
          footerElement={<span><a href="https://www.github.com/" target="_blank">Find Me On Github</a></span>}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
```

I am new to React so i can't figure out how to insert a new row. What might be bonus information is if you want to insert a new row you can choose whether it's gonna be inserted to the first row or the last i.e. with the following option addRowPos:"bottom" .

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and the following works for me.

First, create a reference object to `<ReactTabulator>`.

To do this, initiate the ref in the constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.tableRef = React.createRef(); //create reference object
    }
```

And add the ref in `<ReactTabulator>`.

```
<div>
      </div>
        <ReactTabulator
        ref={this.tableRef}
          columns={editableColumns}
          data={data}
          footerElement={<span><a href="https://www.github.com/" target="_blank">Find Me On Github</a></span>}
          options={options}
        />
```

You can now access the tabulator object as follows:

```
var tabulator = this.tableRef.current.table;
```

To complete your example and bonus question, set up the `onClick` callback:

Define an `onAddRow` method as part of the class. It calls the addRow method of the tabulator object (`this.tableRef.current.table`).

As per http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/update : The second argument of addRow is optional and determines whether the row is added to the top or bottom of the table. A value of true will add the row to the top of the table, a value of false will add the row to the bottom of the table.

```
onAddRow(){
    this.tableRef.current.table.addRow({}, true); //true adds to top
}
```

Bind the `onAddRow` method to `this` in the constructor

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.tableRef = React.createRef(); //create reference object

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.onAddRow= this.onAddRow.bind(this);
    }
```

Call the `addRow` method on a click:

```
<button id="add-row" onClick={this.onAddRow}>Add Row</button>
```

Comment: That is correct. Simply create a ref to refer to ReactTabulator component, hence we have access to tabulator methods, callbacks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've never really used Tabulator myself, but moving from jQuery-based approach to React is mostly about shifting the way you think about things. In React, you take the data (state) and you render your view based on that data (again and again and again - each time the data changes). So instead of calling row-adding functionality on the Tabulator itself (as you do in the sample above), you modify the data (adding the row directly to it), which in turns causes the Tabulator component to be re-rendered with the new row.

So, let the code speak, I guess.

First, you need to save your data in the state of your component:

```
// here we initialize your data state with empty array
// and define setData function that will be used to update 'data'
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

// here we fetch the data from somewhere,
// before your component is mounted for the first time
useEffect(() => {
    // let's say we fetch it using fetch()
    const remoteData = await fetch(...);
    // we set the data to what we fetched using setData;
    // that causes component to re-render;
    // doing data = remoteData does not trigger re-rendering
    setData(remoteData);
},[]);
// this sample assumes that the fetch operation is triggered only once, at startup,
// so that's why empty array is passed as second parameter to useEffect
```

And now we can make modifications to that data so that the Tabulator displays it after adding new row.

```
// we define click handler for the button
const addRowClickHandler = (event) => {
    // we're setting new value of the data array,
    // which is current content of the array plus new empty object;
    // the reason why we do it this way (by making the copy of original data)
    // is because re-rendering is based on detecting the change in the data object;
    // comparison utilizes shallow equality so even after adding new element
    // with push() data===data still returns true
    setData([...data,{}]);
}
```

Your view should now look like that:

```
<div>
    <button id="add-row" onClick={addRowClickHandler}>Add Row</button>
</div>
<ReactTabulator
    columns={editableColumns}
    data={data}
    footerElement={<span><a href="https://www.github.com/" target="_blank">Find Me On Github</a></span>}
    options={options}
/>
```

Happy coding and let me know if it works ;)

Comment: You are right, don't use jquery approach. But the detailed example of implementation of how to insert a row in tabulator table is given in the answer above by @Edwin.